# Using analysis in solving exponential inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

Solve the inequality
$$
35^x+20^x+15^x\le28^x+21^x+25^x,
$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to find the solution by hand and to prove that they are the only ones. I saw that $x=0$ verifies the inequality. But now, I don't know what is the next step.

Answer (score 4):

It's $$(7^x-5^x)(4^x+3^x-5^x)\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $0\leq x\leq2.$